# WebPush Notification in SharePoint Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

How do we enable Web Push feature in SharePoint Intranet Web application every time a new page is added to the library?

I am using SharePoint version 2013.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653183/webpush-notification-in-sharepoint-application

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a web part to show recent modified/added pages.

In the Home Page of your site, add a content search web part to show recent modified items in the site pages library(or the custom library you set to store pages).

You can add it to a page by simply go to edit page > insert > web part > content rollup > content search > add. Here is a guide with more detailed information for your reference:https://sharepointsamurai.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/how-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-for-sharepoint-2013-search/

#### Update:

If you want a push button like facebook, you will need to start from scratch or search for some custom solutions.

The content search web part is a web part showing search results with certain requirements. For your requirements, you can set the web part to show recently changed items, and set the scope according to your requirements. Then the items recently changed will be displayed. 
[image]

Similar requirement:[Push Notifications in SharePoint Portal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233049/push-notifications-in-sharepoint-portal)

Comment: I have gone through the link which you have given as reference, I couldn't see anything like web browser push notification

Comment: @GuruprakashChinnasamy It is a content search web part which you can use custom query. We can use the query to display recently modified/added items. What is web browser push notification you want? Per my knowledge SharePoint does not have a feature named that. Would you like to elaborate your requirements in details so we can find a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is like if someone added any new page or library in to SharePoint application. other people should get the push notification on their browser saying that X person added the new page(example- facebook push notification on browser). this push notification not for mobile

Comment: @GuruprakashChinnasamy I have updated a bit more information ,please have a check.

Comment: Thanks I will try